# Why Microsoft recommends restart after Office removal?

Tags: ms-office, macos

On Microsoft Office Support website: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/uninstall-office-for-mac-eefa1199-5b58-43af-8a3d-b73dc1a8cae3
the last step of uninstallation of Office recommends restarting the computer. Is there any real reason behind that? Why would application removal require a restart? That's something that I connect more with Windows world, where I remember some applications required me to restart the computer after I removed them.

Comment: If your `Office` is still installed, could you run the following command: `launchctl list | grep -i microsoft` and include the result within your original question. My hypothesis is that the Office installer fired a daemon and to be religiously sure it is stopped, Microsoft advised to restart MacOS X. (I haven't Office installed and I can't test it myself).

Comment: I aready installed Office from Mac App Store. That's why I wanted to uninstall my previous installation in the first place - it wasn't from the store, it had its own updater, etc.

Comment: Please add this key information within your original question (edit it).

Comment: Can I ask a question?  If you already had Office365 installed, why would you switch it to the MAS?

Comment: @Marc Wilson what is MAS?

Comment: The Mac App Store.

Comment: @Marc Wilson I switched to App Store version for 2 reasons: easier updates (no Microsoft AutoUpdate application anymore) + I believe in the future it might become the only way of distribution for Mac. I might be wrong about that, but first point already is enough for me to switch to App Store